# Why does DOMParser.parseFromString() return an uninitialized document?

Tags: javascript, dom

Because I am a glutton for embarrassment, I have another in my series of stupid questions about synthetic documents in JavaScript.

So here goes: `createDocument`, `createHTMLDocument`, `new Document()` and `DOMParser.parseFromString()` all return new documents. While the first three all return complete documents, documents returned by `DOMParser.parseFromString()` are uninitialized. Any idea why? (I'm betting on some stupid JavaScript error on my part.)

Here's some code if you want to test:

```
<script>
function doit() {
  var doc1 = document.implementation.createDocument (null, 'html', null);
  console.log(doc1.readyState); // complete

  var doc2 = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("HTML Doc");
  console.log(doc2.readyState); // complete

  var doc3 = new Document();
  console.log(doc3.readyState); // complete

  var parser = new DOMParser; 
  var doc4 = parser.parseFromString("<!doctype html>", "text/html");
  console.log(doc4.readyState); // uninitialized
}
window.onload = doit;
</script>
```

ETA: Above are the results on Firefox. Chrome returns "interactive." Still not sure why.

Comment: Just a guess, but the string could contain elements like `<img>` that need to be loaded asynchronously, and it won't be ready until they're loaded.

Comment: The string in this case is "<!doctype html>", so I'm not sure that that is the issue.

Comment: But it **could** contain other things. So the interface always returns an unready document.

Comment: Adding to the confusion, it looks like `doc4.readyState` is "complete" in IE11.